# Browser Orientation inside pop up - Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, browser, windows-phone-7, orientation

My browser is inside a popup and when we rotate the windows device into the landscape mode, it doesn't auto rotate the browser as well. However, the normal browser (not in the pop up) works well. Does anybody know how to fix this issue automatically or programmatically (that means we catch the rotation event and then rotate the browser ourselves)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my problem is because of third party toolkit, silverlight control toolkit. When I removed the transition page animation code out, things just work

Answer (score 1):

The WebBrowser control will handle this automagicaly.

Just check you have SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" and that you haven't got your emulator in a state where it won't handle orientation changes (ie SIP hidden/hardware keyboard emulation) - restart your emu if not sure.